# A question regarding partitions.

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

Number of partitions of n   = p(n)

Number of partitions of n which has a part equal to 1 = p(n-1)

Number of partitions of n into k parts  = p(n,k)

If for some k the following inequality holds

p(n,k) ≤ p(n-1)

Then does it necessarily imply that all the partitions of n into k parts has a part equal to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for example $p(4,2) = 2 = p(3)$ but there is a partition of $4$ into $2$ parts where neither part is $1$.

Comment: Is there a value or a bound for k such that all the partitions of n into k parts has a part equal to 1 ?

Is it even meaningful to ask this question or is this an impossible condition?